# How can I access image_path route helper inside a Rails 3 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm trying to use Sprockets' image_path method from within a Rails 3 model. I've tried including `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` in my model and calling image_path but that does not work (`undefined local variable or method 'config'`).

Any ideas?

**Update - this worked for me:**

```
ActionController::Base.new.view_context.asset_path("image.png")
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think this is the standard way of loading the asset helper:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("image.png")
```

This seems preferable to creating a new instance of ActionController::Base and asking for the view context in that it is more explicit.